# android crash when trying to switch layouts

Tags: android

My goal: onclick hide main linearlayout and make another linearlayout with picture on top visible

Here is my code I can run the onclick and have the main linearlayout hide but the other layout doesn't showup

```
final LinearLayout jamesaionolayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.jamesaionolayout);
final ImageView jamesaiono = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.jamesaiono);


final LinearLayout textlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.text);
 TextView roster = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jamesaionotext);

 roster.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
         jamesaionolayout.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
         jamesaiono.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
         textlayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }

 });
```

Comment: Please specify what you mean. Does it crash? if so: show the error and stacktrace. If not, but it just doesn't work please look at @sarmad 's answer, and change your title ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make it this textlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: If it "doesn't show up" like the content implies you might be right, but if it "crashes" like the title suggests then this shouldn't matter ofcourse, as `INVISIBLE` is valid too: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE